# Ubuntu's dkms v3.0.6 breaks drivers with enabled SecureBoot

Tags: drivers, apt, 22.10, secure-boot, dkms

#### What happened

I upgraded my system yesterday and it updated dkms to the latest version for Ubuntu 22.10: `dmks3.0.6-2ubuntu1`. At the same time, apt upgraded me to the latest kernel version.

Since then, my nvidia drivers just stopped working.

#### The cause

After some looking, I managed to understand that the nvidia driver found in `/lib/modules/5.19.0-35-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko` is NOT signed, explaining why `modprobe nvidia` outputs:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Key was rejected by service
```

#### The root cause

After some more looking, I came to the conclusion that `dmks3.0.6-2ubuntu1` is the sole reason for my game night being ruined.

*Calling dkms manually*

```
sudo dkms install --force nvidia/525.89.02    
Sign command: /usr/lib/linux-kbuild-5.19/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub
Binary kmod-sign not found, modules won't be signed
...
```

*The bug is known since September 2022*

From [Bug#1019425: dkms 3.0.6-2 not signing modules](https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.bugs.dist/c/UfEMiFgO7CQ), one can read:

> Package: dkms
> Version: 3.0.6-2
> Severity: important
>
> Dear Maintainer,
>
> With dkms 3.0.6-2 the modules are no longer signed. This means that secure-boot
> no longer works.
>
> Back to 3.0.3-4 and and signing works again.

This bug is fixed by `dkms3.0.9`.

### The question

What can I do (No, I cannot disable SecureBoot) to downgrade or upgrade dkms to a working version? `apt list -a dkms` only lists 3.0.6 as available versions for dkms :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix for dkms has been published to Ubuntu's PPA `kinetic-updates`.

You can temporarily add this repository to your sources and upgrade dkms to `dkms3.0.6-2ubuntu2`:

#### Add the repository

```shell
cat | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
# 2023-03-03: Temp fix for dkms 3.0.6 bug
# <https://askubuntu.com/q/1457570/475641>
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates main

^D
```

(note: you might want to choose a mirror closer to you ;)

#### Upgrade dkms

```shell
sudo apt update && sudo apt install dkms
```

#### Fix your drivers

```shell
$ sudo dkms status
nvidia/525.89.02, 5.19.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed
# note that version string

$ sudo dkms remove --force nvidia/525.89.02
[...]

$ sudo dkms install --force nvidia/525.89.02
[...]

$ sudo modprobe nvidia
```

Voilà!

Comment: Personal note: after that I removed the kinetic-updates from my sources as I don't want to beta-test any other package

Comment: Isn't the kinetic-updates repository already active by default? When you write "don't want to beta-test" you might prefer Debian stable over Ubuntu anyways, I think that at the time of writing your answer, dkms version 3.0.10 was the most recent released version (in the github repo, not in the repos active in Ubuntu by default) and the version 3.0.6-2ubuntu2 that you mention here is "with cherry-picks from 3.0.7 upstream git".
(And unfortunately that version doesn't do anything for me, but I also don't want to try anything newer because of "beta" status ;-)